# How do you create a Heap Iterator which runs in O(n) time?

Tags: python, heap

```
def __iter__(self):
    try:
        while True:
            yield self.extract()
    except IndexError:
        return
    return iter([])
```

This is what I'm currently trying to do. The idea is to enumerate all the items in the heap and must run in O(n) time. 
The extract function mentioned above removes the highest priority item from the heap.

Here's the rest of the implementation:

```
from copy import copy 
class Heap:
    """
    A heap-based priority queue
    Items in the queue are ordered according to a comparison function
    """

    def __init__(self, comp):
        """
        Constructor
        :param comp: A comparison function determining the priority of the included elements
        """
        self.comp = comp
        self.heap = []
        self.size = len(self.heap)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.heap)

    def peek(self):
        if self.__len__() == 0:
            raise IndexError
        else:
            return self.heap[0]

    def insert(self, item):
        pass

    def _siftdown(self, startpos, pos):
        newitem = self.heap[pos]
        # Follow the path to the root, moving parents down until finding a place
        # newitem fits.
        while pos > startpos:
            parentpos = (pos - 1) >> 1
            parent = self.heap[parentpos]
            if newitem < parent:
                self.heap[pos] = parent
                pos = parentpos
                continue
            break
        self.heap[pos] = newitem

    def siftup(self, pos):
        endpos = len(self.heap)
        startpos = pos
        newitem = self.heap[pos]
        # Bubble up the smaller child until hitting a leaf.
        childpos = 2*pos + 1    # leftmost child position
        while childpos < endpos:
            # Set childpos to index of smaller child.
            rightpos = childpos + 1
            if rightpos < endpos and not self.heap[childpos] < self.heap[rightpos]:
                childpos = rightpos
                # Move the smaller child up.
                self.heap[pos] = self.heap[childpos]
                pos = childpos
                childpos = 2*pos + 1
        # The leaf at pos is empty now.  Put newitem there, and bubble it up
        # to its final resting place (by sifting its parents down).
        self.heap[pos] = newitem
        self.siftdown(self.heap, startpos, pos)

    def heapify(self,heap,i):
        l = (2*i) + 1
        r = (2*i) + 2 
        if l < len(heap) and heap[l] < heap[i]:
            small = l 
        else:
            small = i
        if r < len(heap) and heap[r] < heap[small]:
            small = r

        if small != i:
            heap[i], heap[small] = heap[small], heap[i]
            self.heapify(heap,small)

    def extract(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise IndexError
        minimum = self.heap[0]
        self.heap[0] = self.heap[-1] 
        self.size -= 1 
        self.heapify(self.heap,0)
        return minimum

    def extend(self, seq):
        pass

    def clear(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            while True:
                yield self.extract()
        except IndexError:
            return
        return iter([])


    def is_empty(self):
        """
        Checks if this heap is empty
        :return: True if the heap is empty
        """
        return len(self.heap) == 0

    def __bool__(self):
        """
        Checks if this heap contains items
        :return: True if the heap is non-empty
        """
        return not self.is_empty()

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        A string representation of this heap
        :return:
        """
        return 'Heap([{0}])'.format(','.join(str(item) for item in self))


def find_median(seq):
    """
    Finds the median (middle) item of the given sequence.
    Ties are broken arbitrarily.
    :param seq: an iterable sequence
    :return: the median element
    """
    if not seq:
        raise IndexError
    min_heap = Heap(lambda a, b: a <= b)
    max_heap = Heap(lambda a, b: a >= b)
    raise IndexError
```

Comment: Could we see the rest of your heap implementation/an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve)?

Comment: In sorted order? Not possible. Most heap implementations iterate in storage order if they provide an iterator at all.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I added the rest of the implementation for your reference.

Comment: Seems problematic because the iterator could very well affect the contents of very thing it's iterating over...so I suspect that overall this is a poor approach to whatever it is your trying to accomplish. i.e. An [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You don't; iterating over the elements of a heap in sorted order is a comparison-based sorting algorithm. Ω(n lg n) is the theoretical lower-bound for such algorithms.

Comment: A self-destructive `__iter__` seems like a *really* bad idea. I think your users will be surprised if  `y = list(x)`  mutates `x`.